# how to edit fasta header?

Tags: header, bioinformatics, fasta

I want to edit fasta header
from this

```
>NR_130660.1 Hanseniaspora uvarum CBS 314 ITS region; from TYPE material
 AAGGATCATTAGATTGAATTATCATTGTTGCTCGAGTTCTTGTTTAGATCTTTTACAATAATGTGTATCT
>NR_131850.1 Cortinarius timiskamingensis NBM D. Malloch 3-9-81/2 ITS region; from TYPE material
 GGAAGTAAAAGTCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTATTGAAATAAACCTGAT
>NR_171752.1 Melanconis marginalis subsp. europaea CBS 131692 ITS region; from TYPE material
AACGACCACCCAGGGCCGGAAACTTCTCCAAACTCGATCATTTAGAGGAAGTAAAAGTCGTAACAAGGTC
```

to this.

```
>NR130660.1_Hanseniaspora_uvarum
 AAGGATCATTAGATTGAATTATCATTGTTGCTCGAGTTCTTGTTTAGATCTTTTACAATAATGTGTATCT
>NR131850.1_Cortinarius_timiskamingensis
 GGAAGTAAAAGTCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTATTGAAATAAACCTGAT
>NR171752.1_Melanconis_marginalis_subsp._europaea
AACGACCACCCAGGGCCGGAAACTTCTCCAAACTCGATCATTTAGAGGAAGTAAAAGTCGTAACAAGGTC
```

I tried for removing with spaces or something.
but I am confused about handling with sequences having the species name with subsp. or var.

Comment: https://www.biostars.org/p/9556299/#9556522

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: Crossposted from biostars.org/p/9556299/#9556522 where there are good answers to this question proposed already

Answer (score 0):

Biopython flavour:

with `input.fa` as input file:

```
>NR_130660.1 Hanseniaspora uvarum CBS 314 ITS region; from TYPE material
 AAGGATCATTAGATTGAATTATCATTGTTGCTCGAGTTCTTGTTTAGATCTTTTACAATAATGTGTATCT
>NR_131850.1 Cortinarius timiskamingensis NBM D. Malloch 3-9-81/2 ITS region; from TYPE material
 GGAAGTAAAAGTCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTATTGAAATAAACCTGAT
>NR_171752.1 Melanconis marginalis subsp. europaea CBS 131692 ITS region; from TYPE material
AACGACCACCCAGGGCCGGAAACTTCTCCAAACTCGATCATTTAGAGGAAGTAAAAGTCGTAACAAGGTC
```

my code :

```
from Bio import SeqIO

from Bio.Seq import Seq

from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

output_seqs = []

for record in SeqIO.parse("input.fa", "fasta"):
    
    #print(record)
    
    new_record = SeqRecord(record.seq)
    
    if record.description.split()[3] == 'subsp.' :

        new_record.id = '_'.join(record.description.split()[0:5])
        
    else:
        
        new_record.id = '_'.join(record.description.split()[0:3])
    
    # print(new_record.description)
    
    new_record.description = ''
    
    output_seqs.append(new_record)
    
    
    
SeqIO.write(output_seqs , 'output.fa' , 'fasta')
```

output as `output.fa` file:

```
>NR_130660.1_Hanseniaspora_uvarum
AAGGATCATTAGATTGAATTATCATTGTTGCTCGAGTTCTTGTTTAGATCTTTTACAATA
ATGTGTATCT
>NR_131850.1_Cortinarius_timiskamingensis
GGAAGTAAAAGTCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTATTGAAA
TAAACCTGAT
>NR_171752.1_Melanconis_marginalis_subsp._europaea
AACGACCACCCAGGGCCGGAAACTTCTCCAAACTCGATCATTTAGAGGAAGTAAAAGTCG
TAACAAGGTC
```